# Is it possible to intercept HTML 5 notifications from a java application?

Tags: java, html, notifications

I've started to work on a little web site, and I'd like to use the HTML 5 notifications from the browser to perform some actions on the client's PC.

In this case I'd like to print something from the printer, by intercepting the desktop notification with a local java application, which is running in background.

1. Is it possible?
2. Do you have any idea/suggestion?
3. Have you ever tried such a thing?

Comment: yes, you need to use the browser application like ActiveX

Comment: isn't there any other way? I prefere to avoid using ActiveX...

Comment: Why? It's so perfect technology, patented in the US.